# Existence of orthogonal matrices with zero diagonal and non-zero off-diagonal values

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Does there exist an orthogonal matrix whose diagonal values are all zero but whose off-diagonal values are all non-zero for *any* $\Bbb R^n$?

Furthermore, does this conclusion change if we are talking about unitary matrices and $\Bbb C^n$?

Comment: Yes. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. In $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ you can create similar situation.

Comment: @user9077 How would you "create a similar situation" for $n = 3$?

Comment: @user9077 do you mean staking them diagonally to make the diagonal entries zero? But my main difficulty is how to ensure the off-diagonal entries are non-zero.

Comment: Let $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Just create a matrix where the columns are $e_n,\ldots,e_2,e_1$ in that order.

Comment: @user9077 For $n > 2$ the resulting matrix has some zero off-diagonal entries.

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't read it carefully. I thought the antidiagonal entries are all non-zero and not off diagonal.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Recall that the columns of an orthogonal matrix are pairwise orthogonal. So, for any $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix $A$ with zero diagonal entries, the dot product of, say, the first two columns is
$$0 = (0, A_{21}, A_{31}) \cdot (A_{12}, 0, A_{32}) .$$

Comment: Thanks but how does this help with the existence, and how does it generalise to $n$?

Comment: When you expand the r.h.s. of the equation in the hint, what does it tell you about existence in the $n = 3$ case?

Comment: I got it. Its about non existence.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.